# How to set azure automation scheduler time zone

Tags: azure, automation, timezone

Now my website is on windows azure. I make a store procedure in database, then I execute it to update database every night on 0:00:00. I use azure automation to achieve this goal. So I write a Runbook which execute this store procedure. And add a scheduler to this task. Now this all work well, but in the scheduler, I set the time "0:00:00" which can't set the time zone.

(I am in China, but this task always run before 0:00:00 compared to my local time)

How can I specify the time zone when setting a scheduler on azure automation?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As you may already know that everything in Azure runs in UTC. If you want to run your task at midnight China time, what you could do is calculate the time difference (which I believe is 8:00 hours) and run your task at that time which would be at 4:00 PM UTC ( assuming my math is right).

Comment: The azure automation scheduler will set the time on your time zone according to your browser, but store the time in UTC time. After know that, I check my store procedure. I found a big mistake that I use GETDATE() to get the current time. But actually this method will return a utc time. So I change it to " DATEADD(hour,  8, GETDATE()) ".Anyway, I'll thank you for your help.